# Torsion $0$-cycle as difference of two points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, algebraic-cycles

If $S$ is an abelian surface over $\mathbb C$, we can always find points $x,y\in S$ such that $x-y\neq 0$ but $2x-2y=0$ in $\mathrm{CH}_0(S)$. Hence my question: for any surface $S$ (or for which surfaces) such that $Alb(S)\neq \{0\}$, is it possible to find $x,y\in S$ such that $x-y\neq 0$ but $2x-2y=0$ in $\mathrm{CH}_0(S)$ ?

Comment: A famous theorem of Roitman may help. It says that the natural map from the Chow group of zero cycles of degree zero to the Albanese is an isomorphism on torsion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Assuming $Alb(S)\neq\{0\}$, we get some $2$ torsion cycles but they are not, a priori in the form $x-y$.

Comment: I did not say Roitman answers this, but it is a start. I am not sure you can get $x,y$ as you want.

Comment: Have you tried to work out this for general curves of large genus?

Comment: I believe the product of two non-hyperelliptic curves should be a counterexample.